# Sampling in an n-dimensional volume defined by supporting experimental data

Tags: machine-learning, python, sampling

I have some experimental data with 5 input parameters that generates one output. There are a few hundred data points that cover a piece of the 5D volume. After training various machine learning models, I'd like to test the models by sampling within the region supported by the data. I started by using Mitchell's Best Candidate sampling (Mitchell DP (1991) Spectrally optimal sampling for distribution ray tracing. Comput Graph 25(4):157–164)over the min and max of the parameters. In 2D, if you had a nearly circular point cloud, min/max would sample regions outside of the point cloud. Thus, the min/max approach samples regions that are unsupported by the data. How might one focus on the region that is supported by the data and ignore the unsupported region?

Another way to ask this might be, given a 5D point cloud of data and a sample point to test, does the test require interpolation or extrapolation?

It is possible that this is called “ Range searching”.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want to sample from the convex hull of your data points (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uniformly/vignettes/convexhull.html). If your data belongs to a lower dimensional manifold, you might have to do something more complicated like the techniques here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am implementing in Python. I do think that your assessment is correct. Thank you.